# Buggy floating point handling in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, floating-point, epsilon

**There's an update in the end!**

I have a little story.

I wanted to calculate the machine epsilon (the largest epsilon > 0 satisfying condition 1.0 + epsilon = 1.0) in a C program compiled by MS Visual Studio 2008 (running on Windows 7 in a 64 bit PC). Since I know that double and float have different precision I wanted to see the answer for both. For that reason I constructed the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef double float_type;
int main()
{
  float_type eps = 1.0;
  while ((float_type) 1.0 + eps / (float_type) 2.0 > (float_type) 1.0)
    eps = eps / (float_type) 2.0;
  printf("%g\n", eps);
  return 0;
}
```

I was quite surprised to see that it gave the same answer for both types double and float: 2.22045e-16. That was strange since double occupies twice more memory than float and should be more precise. After that I looked into [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) and took a sample code from there:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      float machEps = 1.0f;
      do {
        machEps /= 2.0f;
      } while ((float)(1.0 + (machEps/2.0)) != 1.0);
      printf( "\nCalculated Machine epsilon: %G\n", machEps );
      return 0;
   }
```

I was even more surprised when it worked correctly! After some attempts to understand the fundamental difference between the two programs I figured out the following fact: my program (the first one) starts to give the corrent answer for float (1.19209e-07) if I change the loop condition to

```
  while ((float_type) (1.0 + eps / (float_type) 2.0) > (float_type) 1.0)
```

Well, that is a mystery you'd say. Oh, the real mystery is the following. Compare:

```
  while ((float) (1.0 + eps / 2.0f) > 1.0f)
```

which gave the correct answer (1.19209e-07) and

```
  while ((float) (1.0f + eps / 2.0f) > 1.0f)
```

which gave answer which is incorrect for float and correct for double (2.22045e-16).

In fact that is totally wrong, the result should have been opposite. That is because by default constants like 1.0 are treated as double by the compiler (according to the standard) and if it is present in an arithmetic expression then all other operands are promoted to double. Conversely, when I write 1.0f all operands are float and no promotion should take place. And yet I get a completely different result.

After all these tests I tried to compile run the programs on Linux using gcc. No surprise, it printed exactly what I expected (correct answers). So I now guess that this is Visual Studio bug. To make you all laugh (if there are any people who have read my post till that moment what is doubtful ^_^) I will give you another comparison:

```
float c = 1.0;
while ((float) (c + eps / 2.0f) > 1.0f)
```

This does not work properly in VS, but...

```
const float c = 1.0;
```

gives the correct answer of 1.19209e-07.

Please somebody tell me if I am right that the root of the problem is a buggy VS 2008 compiler (can you confirm the bug on your machines?). I would be also  grateful if you tested the case in a newer version: MS VS 2010. Thanks.

**UPDATE.**
With MS Visual Studio 2013 the first program I mentioned works without unexpected results -- it gives appropriate answers for float and double. I checked this with all floating point models (precise, strict and fast) and nothing changed. So it indeed seems that VS 2008 was buggy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Visual Studio's floating-point setting is set to "precise". This means that it will try to make the result as precise as possible. One of the side-effects of this is that intermediates are promoted to double precision.

While I haven't looked at every bit of code you posted, I suspect the problem is here:

```
(float) (c + eps / 2.0f)
```

The `c + eps / 2.0f` is done using double-precision. Each of the 3 operands are promoted to double-precision and the entire expression is evaluated as such. It is only rounded down to a float when you cast it.

If you set the floating-point mode to "strict", it should work as you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately the solution you proposed doesn't seems to work. I tried all types of settings for the floating point model (fast, precise, strict) and it did not help.

The following program (intentionally absurd looking) gives wrong answer:

<pre class="pretypprint lang-c">
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float epsilon = 1.0f;
  while ((float) ((float)1.0f + (float)((float)epsilon / (float)2.0f)) > (float) 1.0f)
    epsilon /= 2.0f;
  printf("%g\n", epsilon);
  return 0;
}
</pre>

Comment: That's interesting. If you set both Visual Studio and GCC to strict floating-point mode, they should always give the same answer. (provided you don't have undefined behavior in the program) If not, then at least one of the compilers has a bug.

Comment: Wow. I am pretty impressed with the speed you answered my comment ^_^
I have tested my program on a 32bit Windows machine with MS VS 2008 and it also gives incorrect result, so the fact that I first ran the program on a 64bit Windows (again VS 2008) was not important.

gcc 4.4.3 gave the corrrect answer. Well, I guess I should write to some Microsoft forum then...

Comment: I just tested the example you put in the comments. It gives `1.19209e-007` under both `strict` and `precise` modes. (I just happened to be online, so I'll get the notification immediately.)

Comment: That's intriguing. Did you use the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 compiler? Under which version of Windows and which machine?

Comment: This was under Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I compiled it for x86. It gave the same result in both `Debug` and `Release`, and for both `Precise` and `Strict` FP-modes.

Comment: A small clarifying notice to the comment starting with "Wow. I am pretty..." (the third one): the independent machine where I tested my code was a 64bit under control of 32 bit Windows Server 2008 (the first machine still 64bit under control of 64 bit Windows 7). Both machines gave incorrect results

Comment: Oh, Mysticial, I would be grateful if you could check whether it works correctly under Visual Studio 2008 SP1. Thanks!

Comment: I still have Visual Studio 2008 (No SP) installed. And it still gives `1.19209e-007` under `Precise`, both `Debug` and `Release`, and both `Win32` and `x64`. This is from a fresh project with default settings. So my guess is that you probably have some other setting enabled that's messing with the results.

Comment: Could you please make sure that your file has a .c extension and, if not, rebuild and rerun the program?

Comment: I just tried it with `.c`. Same result on all the different FP and build modes.

Comment: Is there any way I can contact you and send the project I am building?

Comment: When tested in both vc9 and vc10, I've discovered the following behaviour: if your main file is .c, you get the answer for double, and when you compile .cpp, the answer is for float.